# JOptionPane button arrangement

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

When I use `JOptionPane`, the options are contained in a drop-down menu.
But I want the options are listed as buttons, so that the user can directly click the buttons without clicking the drop-down button first.

My current code:

```
    newHero.setFaction((Faction) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            message,
            title,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            myChoices,
            myChoices[0]
    ));
```

How do I display the options as buttons in a arrangement similar to `FlowLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a option dialog instead of an input dialog...

[image]

```
String[] myChoices = {"Always", "Yes", "No", "Never"};

JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    null, 
    "Happy", 
    "Happy", 
    JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, 
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
    null, 
    myChoices, 
    myChoices[0]);
```